# How to switch environment in CompoundJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, environment

I'm very new to CompoundJS. I'm working on a sample application which accesses data in MongoDB. I'm wondering if there is any way to switch environment in CompoundJS  as we do in Rails (RAILS_ENV = development/test/production). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual in nodejs you can use NODE_ENV variable (same as RAILS_ENV in ruby/rails):

```
NODE_ENV=production node .
```

Should work for compound (from the working dir of your compound project).