# module.export is not working CompoundJS?

Tags: node.js, module, export, mongoose, undefined

I'm new to CompoundJS. I'm working on a sample app. If following the below tutorial:

[Using Mongoose Models](https://github.com/1602/compound/wiki/Using-Mongoose-Models)

I have written the below code in db/schema.js file:

```
customSchema(function () {

   var mongoose = require('mongoose');

   mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database');

   var Schema = mongoose.Schema, ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

   module.exports["mongoose"] = mongoose;

   module.exports["model"] = {}

});
```

In my model.js file (person.js), I have the code below:

```
   var Person = mongoose.model('Person', new module.schema());

   model['Person'] = Person;
```

When I run **compound s** , I'm getting ReferenceError: mongoose is not defined.

Any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wiki is outdated, all documentation currently available at http://compoundjs.com, and i will remove wiki to avoid confusions.

You can use this example if you need mongoose as ORM: https://github.com/anatoliychakkaev/mongoose-compound-example-app

Comment: Hey, thanks. I'll check it out... +1 for you. And I have one more question that I've asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436958/how-to-switch-environment-in-compoundjs. Could you please help me. Thanks again.